# Email scheduler in angluarJs/c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, email, email-templates

I have couple of user reports (Webpages) created using AngularJs in webforms c# application. I need to to create email scheduler which will run on the server once every day. The scheduler will send reports to users.

Because I used angularJs which works in client browser whereas my scheduler would run on the server. It looks like i have to re-write separate server side to convert my email html templates into reports and send to users.

Is there any way that i can use all existing angularJs code and templates and send to users.

Thanks

Comment: You could look at doing some browser automation eg. http://www.seleniumhq.org/ to call your end points and then do something with the output. But that will be messy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Ideally i wouldn't go for selenium like solution. But does that mean there is no other way to achieve what i my question is!!!

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head, as ultimately you would need to render the HTML (including Angular directives) which means that you need some form of JS engine as well, hence the headless browser approach.